# How do I write to an open Excel spreadsheet with ASP.Net using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms, epplus

I have an ASP.Net WebForms site which calculates a value based off an image. This value is then written to an Excel spreadsheet. The calculations work fine, but I am having problems writing the calculated value to the spreadsheet. The ASP.Net WebForm can write to the spreadsheet if the writing occurs as the page opens, but not if the opening and writing are done by different methods. I need the opening and writing to be handled by separate methods, because I'm working on a feature where the user will choose what cell to fill.

How do I write to the spreadsheet with a separate method?

This is what works (one method):

```
protected void openExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string xlsxpath = Server.MapPath("~/new_takeoff.xlsx");
        fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/new_takeoff.xlsx"));
        excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi);
        first = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        ExcelRange chosen = first.SelectedRange;
        first.Cells["I54"].Value = 51;
        excelPackage.Save();

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(xlsxpath);
    }
```

This code doesn't work( writing and opening in separate methods):

```
    protected void openExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string xlsxpath = Server.MapPath("~/new_takeoff.xlsx");

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(xlsxpath);
    }
    protected void updateIT(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/new_takeoff.xlsx"));
        excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi);
        first = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        ExcelRange chosen = first.SelectedRange;
        first.Cells["I54"].Value = 51;
        excelPackage.Save();

    }
```

Comment: There's no need to leave the file open between calls - whenever you want to write to the file: open/write/save/close.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to keep it open was because  I want the user to click on the cell they want to fill.

Comment: Click on the server?

Comment: Could you explain your desired process - with particular attention to what software/program is located on which computer, and at what point an Excel file is needed to be opened before writing to it?

Comment: Every user's computer should have Excel pre-installed because that is the norm in my industry. The spreadsheet should be open before the user calculates anything with the C# code behind. The C# code is an integral part of the ASP.Net Web Forms Application is deployed on my website

Comment: @TimWilliams Clicking on the cell of the Excel Spreadsheet which the user opens from the server

Comment: The server can't open an Excel session on the user's computer.  Your Excel session is opening on the server only.

Comment: I've figured out how to open the spreadsheet on the web browser, but that approach hasn't been friendly to user interaction